# How to add a prefix to all lines that don't start with one of multiple words

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to add a prefix to all the lines in a file that don't start with one of multiple words using sed.

Example :

```
someText
sleep 1
anotherString
sleep 1
for i in {1..50}
do
command
sleep 1
secondCommand
sleep 1
done
```

Should become

```
PREFIX_someText
sleep 1
PREFIX_anotherString
sleep 1
for i in {1..50}
do
PREFIX_command
sleep 1
PREFIX_secondCommand
sleep 1
done
```

I am able to exclude any line starting with a single pattern word (ie: sleep, for, do, done), but I don't know how to exclude all lines starting with one of multiple patterns.
Currently I use the following command :

```
sed -i '/^sleep/! s/^/PREFIX_/'
```

Which works fine on all the lines starting with sleep.
I imagine there is some way to combine pattern words, but I can't seem to find a solution.
Something like this (which obviously doesn't work) :

```
sed -i '/[^sleep;^for;^do]/! s/^/PREFIX_/'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use alternation with multiple words for negation:

```sh
sed -i -E '/^(sleep|for|do)/! s/^/PREFIX_/' file

PREFIX_someText
sleep 1
PREFIX_anotherString
sleep 1
for i in {1..50}
do
PREFIX_command
sleep 1
PREFIX_secondCommand
sleep 1
done
```

`/^(sleep|for|do)/!` will match all lines except those that start with `sleep`, or `for` or `do` words.

Answer (score 2):

I like awk.

```
awk '/sleep|for|do/ { print; next; } { print "PREFIX_" $0 }' filename
```